# Sturm-Liouville form question urgent

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, sturm-liouville

Hi guys so I have this differential of order 2 that I want to get to the Sturm-Liouville form by first finding the $p(x)$.
The form itself is : $(p(x).y'(x))'+q(x).y(x)=0$
And of course, it has equivalent other forms and definitions
And the exercise is : $x^3.y''(x)-x.y'(x)+2y(x)=0$
Is to be turned to the S-L form by finding the $p$ polynomial first as I said.

Thanx much in advance

Comment: Urgent in the sense you have to hand in your homework? No way.

Comment: On this site "urgent" requests will receive less attention.

Answer (score 0):

$$(p(x).y'(x))'+q(x).y(x)=0$$
$$py''+p'y'+qy=0$$
$$y''+\frac{p'}{p}y'+\frac{q}{p}y=0$$
to be compared with
$$y''-\frac{1}{x^2}y'+\frac{2}{x^3}y=0$$
Thus you have to solve :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{p'}{p}=-\frac{1}{x^2} \\
\frac{2}{x^3}=\frac{q}{p}
\end{cases}$$
For a more rigorous manner see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory .